# Tangram YAML, use external function?

Tags: javascript, d3, mapzen

I would like to use some functions from D3 in my Tangram `scene.yaml`, but I'm not finding anything about it in the documentation.

I've tried referencing D3 in the YAML, like so:

```
layers:
    give:
        data: { source: mygeojsonfile }
        draw:
            polygons:
                order: 10000
                color: |
                    function(){
                        var x = d3.scaleLinear()
                            .domain([40, 60])
                            .range([0, 360]);
                        return "hsla(" +
                            x(feature.give) +","+
                            "100%," +
                            "50%," +
                            "100%" +
                            ")";
                    }
                extrude: function(){ return feature.give ; }
```

But it's not working, I get `ReferenceError: D3 is not defined`.

I'm importing D3 before Tangram, so my assumption was that the D3 object would be globally accessible.

My next attempt was to manipulate the color from my `map.js` file.

```
d3.json("give.geojson", function(d){
  d = d.features;
  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(d3.extent(d, function(d){ return d.properties.give; }))
    .range([0, 360]);

  var give = scene.config.layers.give;

  give.draw.polygons.color = "hsla(" +
    x(feature.give) +","+
    "100%, 50%, 100%)";

  scene.updateConfig();
});
```

But this won't work because *feature* will not be defined and I won't be calculating the color for each feature.

I would prefer to make the other option work, since it's less cumbersome writing the code in `map.js` than inside of a string in `scene.yaml`.

Answer (score 2):

Look in style_parser.js in the tangram source to see how your function gets executed.   You may be able to attach library functions to the *global* element of the scene but you might have to write your own scalelinear for this to work nicely.